# Sharepoint 2013 fails to send mention email

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint environment and everything works perfectly except that emails are not being sent whenever somebody mentions somebody else in the microfeeds. The strange things is that emails are working fine and SharePoint is able to send emails.

I looked at the logs and I keep seeing: **MBUtilities.SendAtMentionEmailWorkItem() Failed. To: "email address"**

A Google search returned no results. Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well after much research and looking at the logs I came to the conclusion that the smtp server I was using was not giving access to sharepoint user.

The fix is to allow anonymous access to the stmp server or add the sharepoint account user to smtp server security settings.